# Top bar should distinguish bounty reception from upvotes

Tags: feature-request, bounties, top-bar

*(I've blamed the Top Bar here, but not out of hate. To be honest, I don't recall if the Supercollider did any better.)*

Today, I received a bounty for one of my answers, as you can see here:

> [image: Screenshot]

Well, actually, you can't really see that here. All you can see is I got a lot of rep for one question. It could be lots of upvotes. There doesn't appear to be any way of breaking down how that rep was earned.

I think receiving a bounty is an important enough event to deserve a notification.

Comment: I don't think that's a good title, it implies it's missing...that's not the case.  You'd like it *distinguished*, that's a different request, which is a valid one.  It couldn't be strictly from upvotes in your screenshot since that's not possible in "today" alone, but I take your point about the special-ness of bounties.

Comment: @NickCraver: I acknowledge the rep notification isn't missing. I vaguely recall I got told of bounty awards as notifications before, but I couldn't swear to it. I recorded this is a feature-request, not a bug, for that reason. I am (of course) open to the title being edited for clarity/accuracy. Oh, and good point about +360 being above the daily upvote limit.